# c# asp.net url-rewriting for many pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Website, with ca 80 pages.
For example:

```
www.mycompany.de/login.aspx
www.mycompany.de/orders.aspx
www.mycompany.de/home.aspx
www.mycompany.de/customers.aspx
.....
```

And I want that if you click on a Menu-Point (for example):

```
customers->customers from Germany
```

That the url is "www.mycompany.de" and NOT "www.mycompany.de/customers/customers-from-Germany.aspx".

How can i make that?

Thanks in advance, Patrick!

Comment: Please check hope this helps you, http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/akkiraju/url-rewriting-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: The problem is, that my Website wants to redirect to the 'translation path'. So if I want to st the 'translation path' to "www.mycompany.de", it says that it cant find the site, or always redirects me to index.aspx